# Return names of selected worksheet(s) using excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that has multiple worksheets. While I can only view one worksheet at a time, I can use the Ctrl and Shift keys to select multiple worksheets at the bottom of the excel window. Is there a macro that can help me identify the names of the selected worksheets? I have found this macro while searching for the answer but it returns all worksheet names regardless of the ones that I have selected. Many thanks for your help!

```
Sub worksheetnames()

    Dim selectedSheets As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            selectedSheets = selectedSheets & sheet.Name & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next sheet
    
    If selectedSheets <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Selected sheet names:" & vbCrLf & selectedSheets, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No sheets selected.", vbInformation
    End If

End Sub
```